# Array of structs - deleting/adding elements and printing

Tags: c, arrays, struct, printf

For the below code

```
struct orderSlip
{
    char source[64];
    char destination[64];
    char item[64];  
    int position;
};
//global
struct orderSlip data[100];
```

Is there another way of printing out the data for each element other than these methods below:

```
printf("%s\n",data[0].source);
    printf("%s\n",data[0].destination);
    printf("%s\n",data[0].item);
    printf("%i\n\n", data[0].position);

    printf("%s\n",data[1].source);
    printf("%s\n",data[1].destination);
    printf("%s\n",data[1].item);
    printf("%i\n", data[1].position);
```

etc

```
for(int n = 0; n< 3; n++)
{
    printf("%s\n",data[n].source);
    printf("%s\n",data[n].destination);
    printf("%s\n",data[n].item);
    printf("%i\n\n", data[n].position);
}
```

For deleting and adding, do I have to make a dynamic array of structs? If so, what would be the simplest syntax to do that?
Something like this c++ code

```
int * bobby;
bobby = new int [5];
delete bobby[5];
```

but in C? I'm guessing it has do with malloc and free

Comment: That's `delete[] bobby;`, but yes, you'd need `malloc/free` for doing that in C. I'm sure you can find out how to use dynamic arrays in C with a bit of searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*For deleting and adding, do I have to make a dynamic array of structs? If so, what would be the simplest syntax to do that? Something like this c++ code*"

Not if you know that you will never have more than x amount of items or at least check to make sure you aren't exceeding what you planned was the max. Then you can use your static array.

Adding only requires you to have a variable that keeps track of how many items are  in the array:

```
void add_item(struct orderSlip *p,struct orderSlip a,int * num_items)
{
   if ( *num_items < MAX_ITEMS )
   {
      p[*num_items] = a;
      *num_items += 1;
   }
}
```

Deleting from a static array would require a for loop that would move the items above it down one and decrementing the int keeping track of the number of items.

```
void delete_item(struct orderSlip *p,int *num_items, int item)
{
   if (*num_items > 0 && item < *num_items && item > -1)
   {
      int last_index = *num_items - 1;
      for (int i = item; i < last_index;i++)
      {
         p[i] = p[i + 1];
      }
      *num_items -= 1;
   }
}
```

You could simplify printing the struct by passing it to a function that does the work.

```
void print(const struct orderSlip  *p);
```

or

```
void print(const struct orderslip s);
```

optionally

```
void print(const struct orderslip s, FILE *fp);
```

or

```
void print(const struct orderslip *p, FILE *fp)
{
   fprintf(fp,"%s\n",p->source);
    ...
}
```

and

```
void print_all(const struct orderSlip *p, int num_items)



//global
struct orderSlip data[MAX_ITEMS];
int num_items = 0;



int main(void)
{
...
       print_all(data,num_items);                                       
       strcpy(a.source,"source 2");
       strcpy(a.destination,"destination 20");
       strcpy(a.item,"item xyz");
       a.position = 99;
       add_item(data,a,&num_items);
       print_all(data,num_items);
       delete_item(data,&num_items,0);
       print_all(data,num_items);
```

Comment: delete_item(data,&num_items,0); 0 is the location of the element to be removed; I can delete any element that is located elsewhere (1,2,3,4 etc) but if I tried to delete the first array struct out of 3, the last 2 are the same as element 2 (i'm using qsort() if its any help, the position is the key)

Comment: EDIT: I found the bug:   

         p[item] = p[item + 1];
     suppose to be p[i] = p[i + 1]; now it is properly deleting first element! thanks

Comment: @user1615805 Glad you find my bug. That's what I get for doing a test with only a couple of items...

Comment: @user1615805 Looks like there were at last two bugs in delete_item(). The for loop went one too high. It should stop at (size - 2), not (size - 1).

Comment: Actually, it already does stop at size - 2, which is what "< last_last_index" does.

Comment: That's a really precise answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

One way is to allocate each element in your array and just keep an array of pointers

```
struct orderSlip **data;

data = calloc(100, sizeof(struct orderSlip*)); // 100 pointers to struct
```

(calloc will make sure memory is zero:ed from the start)

everytime you add a new struct:

```
data[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct orderSlip));
```

and when you don't need any longer

```
free(data[i]);
```

You can also change the size of data by using realloc, [see](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/)

If you don't need to access the array using index, you could instead consider another type of data structure like a linked list to be truly dynamic.

Comment: thank you, but looking at this its more difficult than I thought, I already have a specified amount of max items, and will use that instead of dynamically allocating. Thanks for your time though!